# What’s their name?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, possessive-pronouns

I found in my book below sentence. Is it correct?

> What’s their name?

If it's correct, I can answer "Their name is Alex and Ann.", isn't it?

Is it spoken version of "What are their names?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it spoken version of "What are their names?"

No.

> What's their name?

Here, "their" is the "gender neutral" determiner; you use it when you are talking about someone whose gender you don't know, or when you don't want to mention "his" or "her". If I tell you *"Hey, there is someone here to see you."*, you would reply *"Yeah? Who is it? What is their name?"*

> [Their](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/their): used to refer to one person in order to avoid saying "his or her" (Cambridge)
>
> - One of the students has left their book behind.

Comment: I' m learning relative clause. I have this example:

    Sally stayed with some friends. What’s their name? --> What is the name of the friends Sally stayed with?

So, I don't understand, if "What’s their name?" is singlar why the answer isn't "What is the name of the friend Sally stayed with?"

Or is there an additional rule for this example?

Comment: Essential.Grammar.in.Use.Supplementary.Exercises. Exercise N183.

Comment: So, as I understand this sentence would be "Sally stayed with some friends. What're their names? --> What are the names of the friends Sally stayed with?", isn't it?

Comment: @Sergey Yes, your last comment sounds right. We would use the plural. To me, the singular version in this case seems like a mistake. Also note that the book has them in quotes.